# Javascript code that show what is not equal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This code show if two arrays of objects are true or not and it's good... how to manage this code to log what answer is not equal?

Model of arrays, arrayA is array of user answered questions, and arrayB is correct answers

```
arrayA: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
arrayB: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
```

Pushing function:

```
arraysEqual(arrayA, arrayB)
```

```
arraysEqual = (a1, a2) =>
    a1.length === a2.length &&
    a1.every((o, idx) => this.objectsEqual(o, a2[idx]));

  objectsEqual = (o1, o2) =>
    typeof o1 === "object" && Object.keys(o1).length > 0
      ? Object.keys(o1).length === Object.keys(o2).length &&
        Object.keys(o1).every(p => this.objectsEqual(o1[p], o2[p]))
      : o1 === o2;
```

Comment: which thing isn't working correctly in this code?

Comment: Everything works good! Just trying to make code from this code to log what is not equal..just can't get it but I think that is just little to work but simply cannot get it @ChrisRollins

Answer (score 0):

What about a function that returns an array of the indexes in which a1 and a2 differ?

Something like:

```
function arraysUnequal(a1, a2)
{
   let result = [];
   let maxindex = (a1.length > a2.length) ? a1.length : a2.length;
   for (let i = 0; i < maxindex; i++)
   {
      if (!objectsEqual(a1[i]||{}, a2[i]||{})) { result.push(i) }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you Jos for effort that is also working but trying to get what objects in this two arrays is not equal